# Rails - How to add values in seperate objects together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

You have an array of objects which contain a key-value reference.

```
[{booking_ref: 'w578383', foo: 'bar', price1: 500, price2: 30],
{booking_ref: 'w578383', foo: 'bar', price1: 600, price2: 40},
{booking_ref: 'r123523', foo: 'bar', price1: 699, price2: 4}]
```

I want to:

- group objects by key-value reference (booking_ref)
- go through those groupings and to each object add the financial values only together (price1 and price2 to the other booking's price1 and price2)
- collapse out of groupings back to an array of objects which contain a key-value reference. That would now be:

  ```
  [{booking_ref: 'w578383', foo: 'bar', price1: 1100, price2: 70},
  {booking_ref: 'r123523', foo: 'bar', price1: 699, price2: 4}]
  ```

I am thinking:

```
objects.group_by(&:booking_ref).each {|group|
  group.merge {|key, value1, value2| value1 + value2 if key == price1 || price2}
}
```

Does that work and if so **how do I then return them back out of the group_by state?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you can use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) you can use some form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) or [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`), and vice-versa. Others have used `group_by`, so here's a hash-merge answer.

Letting the variable `bookings` equal your array of hashes, you can write the following.

```
keys_to_aggregate = [:price1, :price2]

bookings.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:booking_ref]=>g) { |_,o,n|
  keys_to_aggregate.reduce(o) { |f,k| f.merge(k=>o[k] + n[k]) } } }.values
  #=> [{:booking_ref=>"w578383", :foo=>"bar", :price1=>1100, :price2=>70},
  #    {:booking_ref=>"r123523", :foo=>"bar", :price1=>699, :price2=>4}]
```

Note that before [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) at the end of the expression is evaluated we have the following.

```
bookings.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:booking_ref]=>g) { |_,o,n|
  keys_to_aggregate.reduce(o) { |f,k| f.merge(k=>o[k] + n[k]) } } }
  #=> {"w578383"=>{:booking_ref=>"w578383", :foo=>"bar", :price1=>1100, :price2=>70},
  #    "r123523"=>{:booking_ref=>"r123523", :foo=>"bar", :price1=>699, :price2=>4}}
```

This uses the form of `Hash#update` that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for details, particularly the definitions of the value-determining block's three variables (`k`, `o` and `n`). (I've substituted `_` for `k` [the key] to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.)

Comment: It works thank! One thing is there a way to refactor it away from having to list each price in one long line. In reality there are 5/6 prices which need to be merged.

Comment: I modified the method to address that.

Comment: @JamesJY: If this code works fine for your data structure, I really don't understand why it shouldn't work with my code. Anyway, you usually can't go wrong with Cary's answers.

Answer (score 1):

With hash objects, you could calculate the sums and merge them back to the first hash in each group :

```
bookings = [
{booking_ref: 'w578383', foo: 'bar', price1: 500, price2: 30},
{booking_ref: 'w578383', foo: 'bar', price1: 600, price2: 40},
{booking_ref: 'r123523', foo: 'bar', price1: 699, price2: 4}
]

grouped_bookings = bookings.group_by{ |h| h[:booking_ref] }.map do |ref, hs|
  sums = hs.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |h, sum|
    %i(price1 price2).each do |price|
      sum[price] += h[price].to_i
    end
  end
  hs.first.merge(sums)
end

p grouped_bookings
# [{:booking_ref=>"w578383", :foo=>"bar", :price1=>1100, :price2=>70},
# {:booking_ref=>"r123523", :foo=>"bar", :price1=>699, :price2=>4}]
```

Comment: @JamesJY: Yes, my objects are hashes, yours probably aren't. Since you didn't include any object definition, I had to use hashes. You could replace the `hash[:key]` calls with `object.key` method calls.

Comment: @JamesJY: Please update your question with the code to initialize your objects.

Comment: It's still not clear what these objects are. They look like hashes but apparently aren't. What's their class?

Answer (score 0):

First, `group_by` is fine, then use a `map` to iterate the hash and then reduce the value from a list to a sum using `inject`

```
objects.group_by(&:booking_ref)
       .map{|ref, list| {booking_ref: ref, 
                        price1:  => list.inject(0){|sum,h| sum + h.price1},
                        price2: => list.inject(0){|sum,h| sum + h.price2}
                        }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking an object-oriented approach here, you can get this looking quite neat and elegant. The key is to define the `+` method on the object. Full example below:

```
class Booking
  attr_accessor :booking_ref, :foo, :price1, :price2

  def initialize(params={})
    params.each { |key, value| send "#{key}=", value }
  end

  # add up prices, and return new Booking object
  def +(other)
    new_obj = self.dup
    new_obj.price1 += other.price1
    new_obj.price2 += other.price2
    new_obj
  end
end

# set up example bookings
bookings = [
  Booking.new(booking_ref: 'w578383', foo: 'bar', price1: 500, price2: 30),
  Booking.new(booking_ref: 'w578383', foo: 'bar', price1: 600, price2: 40),
  Booking.new(booking_ref: 'r123523', foo: 'bar', price1: 699, price2: 4)
]


# grouping becomes very simple - potentially a one-liner
bookings.group_by(&:booking_ref).map { |_, values| values.reduce(&:+) }
# => [
        #<Booking:... @booking_ref="w578383", @foo="bar", @price1=1100, @price2=70>,
        #<Booking:... @booking_ref="r123523", @foo="bar", @price1=699, @price2=4>
     ]
```